grpc-dotnet retry with Polly even if connection could not be established (HttpMessageHandler is not called)
Why is not called Polly policy http message handler when connection could not be established?
I would like to retry even if connection could not be established, the service might be restarting when I'm doing the grpc call.
How can I add http message handler which will be called even during connection?
serviceCollection
    .AddGrpcClient<TGrpcClientType>(option =>
    {
        option.Address = new Uri(configuration.EndpointAddress);
        option.CallOptionsActions.Add(ctx =>
            ctx.CallOptions = ctx.CallOptions
                .WithDeadline(DateTime.UtcNow.Add(configuration.Deadline)));
    })
    .AddPolicyHandler(retryFunc);      

This sample code was taken from past discussion https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/686
Func<HttpRequestMessage, IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>> retryFunc = (request) =>
{
    return Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.Headers.GetValues("grpc-status").FirstOrDefault() != "0")
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, (input) => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3 + input), (result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
        {
            var grpcStatus = (StatusCode)int.Parse(result.Result.Headers.GetValues("grpc-status").FirstOrDefault() ?? "0");
            Console.WriteLine($"Request failed with {grpcStatus}. Retry.");
        });
};    

Link to grpc-dotnet issue

Have you tried to debug whether this r.Headers.GetValues("grpc-status").FirstOrDefault() != "0" evaluates to true? The sample code is almost 5 years old, a lots thing could have changed since then.
